# What is the Attributes property used for in a HtmlTargetElement attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tag-helpers

The way an attribute is set on an asp.net core tag helper is as follows:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("test1",Attributes = "make",ParentTag = "myparent")]
```

I'm not understanding the syntax `Attributes = "make"`

I know Attributes is a string that gets passed into the constructor of `HtmlTargetElement` but what I don't get is the `= "make"` part. If this were the call list of the method I now that would mean make is the value if null is passed in but I don't understand it when it's on the call method side.

What is the Attributes property used for in a `HtmlTargetElement` attribute?

Comment: Attributes is a property of the attribute that is set to "make".

Comment: I'm not following: "property of the attribute"

Comment: I got it.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84c42s56(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The type HtmlTargetElementAttribute has a property named Attributes, the syntax is equivalent to new HtmlTargetAtribute("test1") { Attributes="make" }.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `HtmlTargetElement` attribute is used to specify additional criteria for a TagHelper to use when determining a match. The Attributes property specifies that an html element must contain that value to match. The attribute:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("test1",Attributes = "make")]``
```

Would match the following element:

```
<test1 make></test1>
```

Also keep in mind that you can decorate a class with multiple `[HtmlTargetElement]` attributes to result in a logical-OR.

For more examples see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring#getting-started-with-tag-helpers)

For official documentation of `HtmlTargetElement.Attributes` see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.taghelpers.htmltargetelementattribute)